# Fail to drop table column in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

Version: cnosdb 2.3.2, revision 5378a3d6e12ccde5a8c2236eca1349caf6f7eb86
Mode: singleton

```
$ ./target/debug/cnosdb-cli
CnosDB CLI v2.3.2
Input arguments: Args { host: "localhost", port: 8902, user: "root", password: None, private_key_path: None, database: "public", tenant: "cnosdb", precision: None, target_partitions: None, stream_trigger_interval: None, data_path: None, file: [], rc: None, format: Table, quiet: false, write_line_protocol: None, use_ssl: false, use_unsafe_ssl: false, cacert: [], chunked: false }
public ❯ CREATE TABLE air (
                    visibility DOUBLE,
                    temperature DOUBLE,
                    pressure DOUBLE,
                    TAGS(station));
Query took 0.021 seconds.
public ❯ ALTER TABLE air ADD FIELD humidity DOUBLE;
Query took 0.018 seconds.
public ❯ ALTER TABLE air DROP humidity;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"050019","error_message":"grpc client request error: DataSchemaError: database 'public' not found"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug for cnosdb and has been worked on in the latest version